# According to Catholic scholars, why was Blessed Virgin Mary spared of temptations on her way to motherhood?

Tags: catholicism, virgin-mary, temptation

We see that Blessed Virgin Mary had a rather smooth travel on her way to giving birth to Jesus, bar the physical hardship of travelling to Bethlehem towards the end of her pregnancy and trying to find a place to stay. She did not have to face any temptation say, the Devil threatening her that she would be abandoned by  Joseph, and  that  Herod would send his men to kill her son etc. Jesus, on the other hand, was made to face temptations right at the beginning of his public mission.

My question therefore is: **According to Catholic scholars, why was Blessed Virgin Mary spared of temptations on her way to motherhood?**

Comment: She was not spared, but rather, Satan knew fully well God's Holy Decree in Genesis3:15. Satan was unsuccessful during Mary's childhood years because She spent it in the Temple praying daily. And in the instance, where Satan thought he could now tempt Mary, after She left the temple, Satan was puzzled at the majestic soul of Mary, how pure and immaculate it was. And then, St.Gabriel annunciation revealed that Mary was the "Woman in Genesis3:15, and after that, Satan knew, he must bow down too. Satan feared so much, getting near to the Sovereign Queen, which he and fallen angels are subject to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**According to Catholic scholars, why was Blessed Virgin Mary spared of temptations on her way to motherhood?**

Little to nothing has been written on the actual personal temptations Mary endured in her life, this includes any apocryphal writings. To be honest, it does not pertain to our salvation, but to her own particular salvation.

It is true that according to Catholicism, Mary is believed to be immaculately conceived and did not commit any real personal sin, but these graces did not preserve Mary from being tempted to sin.

If Jesus himself was tempted in the ways men are; then logic tells us that his Mother would have been equally tempted as men are.

Although the Blessed Virgin Mary received the unique personal privilege of the immaculate conception. This privilege is not extended to her being so sheltered in her earthly pilgrimage that she was never tempted to sin, thus Mary’s own salvation came through Jesus Christ albeit in an exceptional manner because she never sinned.

> The Blessed Virgin Mary was immaculately conceived without original or actual sin. She also did not suffer from concupiscence, which is defined by the Catechism of the Catholic Church as “the movement of the sensitive appetite contrary to the operation of the human reason” (CCC 2515). While Scripture does not record whether or not the Blessed Virgin experienced temptations, we do know from Scripture that her Son did experience temptations (Matt. 4:1–11). If it was possible for God the Son, who was also without sin and without concupiscence, to experience temptations, then we can conclude that it was at least within the realm of possibility for the Blessed Virgin to experience temptations. - [Did Mary Have Temptations?](https://catholicsay.com/did-mary-have-temptations/?amp=1)

Answer (score 2):

Per Catholic doctrine, Mary was without sin. There is no specific mention of her temptations, but as [pointed out](https://www.catholic.com/qa/did-mary-have-temptations) on Catholic.com, if Jesus was tempted, it's certainly possible Mary was as well. I certainly can't find any reference to a belief among Catholic scholars that she *wasn't* tempted. Without original sin, she would not have experienced "concupiscence," that is, a [corrupted internal appetite](http://www.scborromeo.org/ccc/para/2515.htm), but that's obviously not required for temptation or Jesus wouldn't have experienced temptation.

As to why it's not recorded, as John points out, if they tried to record everything Jesus did, it would be way too many books. That would be doubly true if they tried to record other important Biblical characters too.

Mary being tempted would sure make an interesting story, but it looks like it's going to have to remain speculation until we get to heaven and have a chat. :)

Answer (score 0):

*According to Catholic scholars, why was Blessed Virgin Mary spared of temptations on her way to motherhood?*

There were no concrete writings or evidence pointing to this subject. But, we can infer, why Satan and his demons do not dare try to tempt Mary on Her way to Motherhood.

Satan appeared to Eve indwelling a serpent. Satan appeared to Jesus too, but the gospel is silent in what form Satan had appear.

Satan could appear to Eve in his angelic form, but he opted not, why?
Satan is no longer the bearer of light, perhaps, Satan having a false light, if he appears to Adam and Eve, will be seen as inferior creature, because Adam had a greater light coming from God, while Satan no longer have the light of God.

So, if you were Satan, what form will you choose if you want to go near to Mary? Would a serpent, repeating the tricks to Eve will do? Perhaps a fallen angel with false light or a human image perhaps?

Satan knew the bible, and certainly understand fully who is the chosen
Woman in Genesis3:15, and going near to the Woman who is destined to crush his ugly proud head, is definitely a No No for Satan.

1. **The Mystery of Annunciation.**

St. Gabriel profound greetings made Satan and his demons tremble in fear.

Before St. Gabriel was sent, Mary only look upon herself as a lowly servants, no title, no privileges. But the lowly state of Mary saying, "I am the handmaid of the Lord", was changed by St.Gabriel profound and mysterious "greetings". The handmaid or lowly servants is now vested with royal garments fit for a Queen not just here on earth but also in Heaven, as St.Gabriel a high ranking cherubim, nearest to the Throne of God, showed a gesture that Satan and his demons trembled in fear. A high ranking cherubim, "bow down", and revealed, the anointed position of the woman who only saw herself as lowly servant. Mary is no longer a handmaid, but a Queen, from **"i am to I AM"**. And ofcourse, the 17th century theologians saw the mystery of annunciation as Mary's ordination into a Virgin Priest, that subjected not only fallen mankind, but also, the Heavenly Host including Satan and his demons.

2. **The Mystery of Visitation**

St. Gabriel mysterious greetings, is a heavenly formula for invoking the Holy Spirit, to pour down all the gifts and graces to a deserving soul. Since, Mary's soul was emptied, the pouring down of all the gifts and graces was "full", and Mary was "full of grace".

And, we can see the parallelism, minutes after the annunciation, Mary like St. Gabriel, can also invoke the pouring down of graces and gifts, as Mary's simple and mysterious greetings, was able to pour down the gifts, not just on St.Elizabeth but also to St.John the Baptist, filling them both, with the sanctifying gifts of the Holy Spirit.

In the Christian world, only the soul filled with the Holy Spirit can proclaimed, *"Jesus is Lord"*, and St.Elizabeth was the first born-again Christian, who was filled with the Holy Spirit, that empower her to proclaimed, "Jesus is Lord".

3. The Priest have the power to exorcise demons, and Mary is not just an ordinary priest nor a Bishop ordained in the sacramental orders, but Mary's Priesthood was ordained by a "celestial prophet", it was St. Gabriel who was sent to ordained Mary into a Royal Priest, with a magnitude of a Sovereign Queen, that made all the Heavenly Host subjected to Her, including Satan and his demons.

See the [The Mysteries of the Rosary: Joyful Mysteries](https://www.vatican.va/special/rosary/documents/misteri_gaudiosi_en.html)

In closing, if you were Satan and his demons, and you know that you are all subjected to Mary's Queenship, will you dare to go near or fight a Queen?

That's why, all Exorcist Priest, esp. the famous, late Chief Exorcist named Fr.Garielle Amorth, testified to the power of mentioning and invoking the powerful name of Mary, and Her presence during exorcism, made all demons tremble in fear even Satan.

> **"Anyone who goes to Mary and pray the holy rosary cannot be touched by Satan."-Fr.Amorth.**

Eve was "touched" by Satan, but the Blessed Virgin Mary, the New Eve was never touch by Satan, and also all Her children. Satan cannot touch a soul, carried in the loving and powerful arms of Mary, the Sovereign Queen of Heaven and Earth.

> [Ad Caeli Regnam](https://www.vatican.va/content/pius-xii/en/encyclicals/documents/hf_p-xii_enc_11101954_ad-caeli-reginam.html)
>
> ENCYCLICAL OF POPE PIUS XII
> ON PROCLAIMING THE QUEENSHIP OF MARY
> TO THE VENERABLE BRETHREN, THE PATRIARCHS, PRIMATES,
> ARCHBISHOPS, BISHIOPS, AND OTHER LOCAL ORDINARIES
> IN PEACE AND COMMUNION WITH THE HOLY SEE
>
> Venerable Brethren, Health and Apostolic Blessing.
>
> From the earliest ages of the catholic church a Christian people, whether in time of triumph or more especially in time of crisis, has addressed prayers of petition and hymns of praise and veneration to the Queen of Heaven. And never has that hope wavered which they placed in the Mother of the Divine King, Jesus Christ; nor has that faith ever failed by which we are taught that Mary, the Virgin Mother of God, reigns with a mother's solicitude over the entire world, just as she is crowned in heavenly blessedness with the glory of a Queen.